# Cannot convert void to double

Tags: java, double, converters, void

If anyone could give me some pointers or a solution that would be great. I;m trying to have the code run an automobile mpg calculator

When I run my code I get an error as follows:

```
U:\gasProj.java:32: error: incompatible types: void cannot be converted   to double
        fuelLeft=bmw.takeTrip(100);
```

Here is my code.

```
public class gasProj{
public static class Automobile{
    double mpg=0;
    Automobile(double a)
    {
        mpg=a;
    }

    private double fuel=0.0;
    public void fillup(double gas)
    {
        fuel=fuel+gas;
    }


    public void takeTrip(double miles)
    {
        fuel=fuel-miles/mpg;
    }

    public double printFuel()
    {
        System.out.println(fuel);
    }
}


    public static void main(String[]args){
        Automobile bmw=new Automobile(24);
        bmw.fillup(20);
        double fuelLeft;
        fuelLeft=bmw.takeTrip(100);

    }

}
```

Comment: `public void takeTrip`. You tell java the method has a void return type, then to use it as if it returns something.

Comment: Never mind running - does this actually compile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change `takeTrip` to:

```
public double takeTrip(double miles)
{
    fuel=fuel-miles/mpg;
    return fuel;
}
```

Currently, `takeTrip` doesn't return anything, so you can't assign the return value to a double.

Answer (score 1):

The method `takeTrip()` returns void, meaning it returns no value.
In order to assign to `fuelLeft`, you need another method to return the `fuel` variable value.

```
public double getFuel(){
  return fuel;
}
```

Now, `fuelLeft` will have a valid value.

```
fuelLeft = bmw.getFuel();
```